# Is this the right way to supplement AdMob when iAd is unavailable?

Tags: ios, admob, iad

I want to fill the iAd space with AdMob advertisements when iAd is unavailable and was wondering if this was the right way to code it to do so. Every time I've run my simulator it has displayed iAd, and when it doesn't it shows a white strip, so I'm wondering if I've coded it wrong. Could someone help me out, and fix the code if necessary, or add suggestions. Thanks.

```
//iAd Advertising
#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    advertisement.hidden = NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    //bannerView_.hidden = YES;

} // if there is an internet connection, load the iAd with a 1 second fade in effect

- (void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    advertisement.hidden = YES;


    bannerView_.hidden = NO;
    bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50)];
    bannerView_.adUnitID = @"//pubname";
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right. I'm guessing the error is in the storyboard. On the storyboard click the iAd and make sure the Alpha is set to 0. That should solve it.

Sorry for the late answer.